# How to read specific tag in XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

**This is my Xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Colleges>
    <College id="1" >
        <Name>Guru Kashi University</Name>
        <ShortName>GKU</ShortName>
        <Address>Talvandi Sabo</Address>
        <City>Bathinda</City>
        <Contact>09876543210</Contact>    
     </College>

     <College id="2" >
        <Name>Shaheed Udham Singh</Name>
        <ShortName>SUS</ShortName>
        <Address>Tangori</Address>
        <City>Mohali</City>
        <Contact>01234567890</Contact>    
     </College>
  </Colleges>
```

I want to read all the attributes College tag where id =1

but i dont know how to read it

Comment: Can you show what do you know? It is really unclear what part of the process you have problem with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ to XML very easily.  Assuming you have the XML above a string:

```
// Use XDocument.Load(fileName) if the XML is in file.
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // xml is the XML string

var query = from x in xDoc.Descendants("College")
            where x.Attribute("id").Value == "1"
            select x.Elements;
```

The above will give you a collection of all the elements under the `College` element that has an id of 1.

Alternatively, you can create an anonymous type:

```
var query = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("College")
             where x.Attribute("id").Value == "1"
             select new {
                 Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
                 ShortName = x.Element("ShortName").Value,
                 Address = x.Element("Address").Value,
                 City = x.Element("City").Value,
                 Contact = x.Element("Contact").Value
             }).SingleOrDefault();
```

In this case, I used SingleOrDefault to get the only value (or no value if it isn't found); if you could have more than one "id"=1 then remove the SingelOrDefault and you'll have a collection of the anonymous types.

You can then access the data like this:

```
query.Name
query.ShortName
```

etc.

Comment: thnx Tim ... its working ..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XDocument` and `Linq`

```
XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Parse(@" <Colleges> <College id=""1"" > <Name>Guru Kashi University</Name> <ShortName>GKU</ShortName> <Address>Talvandi Sabo</Address> <City>Bathinda</City> <Contact>09876543210</Contact> </College>  <College id=""2"" > <Name>Shaheed Udham Singh</Name> <ShortName>SUS</ShortName> <Address>Tangori</Address> <City>Mohali</City> <Contact>01234567890</Contact> </College> </Colleges>");

var result = xDoc1.Root.Elements("College")
                                          .Where(x => x.FirstAttribute.Name == "id" && 
                                                     x.FirstAttribute.Value == "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Your xml file path"));

XmlNodeList nodeList = MenuListNode.SelectNodes("//College");
string value= "";

if(nodeList.Attributes("id").Value.Equals("1"))
{
    value = nodeList.Attributes("id").Value.ToString() + "|";
    foreach (XmlNode MenuNode in MenuListNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        value = value + MenuNode.InnerText.ToString() + "|";
    }
}
```

Now the value will give the text of child nodes of node college whose id attribute is 1 with pipe separated.Please inform if this is helpfull